# Что такое тривиальный класс, конструктор и деструктор в с++

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, стандарт, деструктор

В С++ довольно часто встречаются понятия : тривиальный
   класс, деструктор, конструктор. Что означает тривиальный с точки
   зрения компилятора?

Comment: `inline` функции не определяются по объему тела

Comment: Просто, как я читал - inline - это рекомендация компилятору и она может быть выполнена в зависимости от "объема/сложности" встраиваемого кода.

Comment: @BadCatss ключевое слово `inline`, в первую очередь, — это механизм, позволяющий писать код так, чтобы у компилятора **была возможность** её встроить. Рекомендация сделать это — вторичный эффект. С точки зрения языка функция является или не является `inline`'овой *независимо* от того произошло ли по факту встраивание или нет...

Comment: Все эти определения есть в стандарте (например, [тривиальный копирующий конструктор](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#11)). В одном месте многое собрано [тут](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/29/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx) в разделе "Тривиальность"

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, отредактирую вопрос. И еще, хотел уточнить: т.е если я напишу ключевое слово inline - то функция будет inline , даже если не будет встраивание? И что подразумивается под "была возможность ее встроить" ?
Т.е это что то типа булевого разрешения -  что эту можно встраивать, а вот эту нельзя?
Как этот механизм работает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Если можно, то наверное оформлю про inline - отдельный вопрос, если Вам не трудно - ответьте  на него.

Comment: @cppquestions, спасибо, сейчас буду читать.

Comment: @BadCatss, компилятор может также встраивать и функции без атрибута *inline*... (зависит от компилятора, ключей вызова и ... (иногда такое его поведение может обескураживать))

Comment: @BadCatss, да, если написать ключевое слово `inline` перед объявлением функции (или если оно подразумевается), то с **точки зрения языка** она, сюрприз, будет являться *inline-функцией*. Под «возможностью встроить» я подразумеваю, что классические компиляторы Си/C++ принципиально могут встроить функцию только определённую в рамках той же *единицы трансляции*… `inline` собственно и позволяет программисту определить её таким образом (читай в хедере) и избежать дублирования как объектного кода, так и ошибок множественного определения при линовке.

Comment: И да, компилятор при этом вправе встроить любую функцию, не нарушая результат вычислений, в зависимости от своих хитроумных эвристик, багов, ключей компиляции или чего-то поинтересней...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно будет спросить: что означает тривиальный (класс, конструктор, деструктор и т.д.) с точки зрения стандарта, а не компилятора.

Это обширный вопрос (нужно пройтись по всем сущностям, которые называются тривиальными) поэтому вам следует самостоятельно обратиться к стандарту C++.

Например, согласно стандарту C++ 17 (12 Classes) класс называется тривиальным, если он тривиально копируемый.

> 6 A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> (6.1) — where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment
>   operator, and move assignment operator (15.8, 16.5.3) is either
>   deleted or trivial,
>
> (6.2) — that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move
>   constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
>   and
>
> (6.3) — that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor (15.4).
>
> **A trivial class is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or
>   more default constructors (15.1), all of which are either trivial or
>   deleted and at least one of which is not deleted.** [ Note: In
>   particular, a trivially copyable or trivial class does not have
>   virtual functions or virtual base classes. — end note ]

Для определения тривиальности конструкторов и деструкторов следует обратиться сначала к следующему разделу стандарта (11.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions)

> 5. ... A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted 
>      or deleted on its first declaration
>
> 6 [Example:
>
> ```
>   struct trivial {
>       trivial() = default;
>       trivial(const trivial&) = default;
>       trivial(trivial&&) = default;
>       trivial& operator=(const trivial&) = default;
>       trivial& operator=(trivial&&) = default;
>       ~trivial() = default;
>   };
>
>   struct nontrivial1 {
>       nontrivial1();
>   };
>   nontrivial1::nontrivial1() = default; // not first declaration
> ```
>
> — end example ]

То есть определенный пользователем конструктор или деструктор не может быть тривиальным. Иначе конструктор или деструктор являются тривиальными при выполнении следующих дополнительных условий

(C++ 17, 15.1 Constructors):

> 6 **A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided** and if:
>
> (6.1) — its class has no virtual functions (13.3) and no virtual base
>   classes (13.1), and
>
> (6.2) — no non-static data member of its class has a default member
>   initializer (12.2), and
>
> (6.3) — all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default
>   constructors, and
>
> (6.4) — for all the non-static data members of its class that are of
>   class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
>   constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial

(C++ 17, 15.4 Destructors)

> 6 **A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided** and if:
>
> (6.1) — the destructor is not virtual,
>
> (6.2) — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial
>   destructors, and
>
> (6.3) — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are
>   of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial
>   destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is non-trivial